# mmap open and read from file

Tags: c++, mmap

I am mapping a huge file to avoid my app thrashing to main virtual memory, and to be able to run the app with more than the RAM I have. The code is c++ but partly follows old c APIs. When I work with the allocated pointer, the memory does get backed to the file as desired. However, when I run the app next time, I want the memory to be read from this same file which already has the prepared data. For some reason, on the next run, I read back all zeros. What am I doing wrong? Is it the ftruncate call? Is it the fopen call with wrong flag? Is it the mmap flags?

```
int64_t mmbytes=1<<36;
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w+");
int fd = fileno(file);
int r = ftruncate(fd, mmbytes );
if (file == NULL || r){
    perror("Failed: ");
    throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
} // 

if ((mm = mmap(0, mmbytes,  
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
  {
        fprintf(stderr,"mmap error for output, errno %d\n", errno);
        exit(-1);
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Where is the code for reading the file? How big is your matrix in bytes and is it equal to both `mmbytes` and `sizeof(mymatrix) * DIM`? Yes, opening a file in write mode and then reading from it is a problem.

Comment: Also note that mmapping a huge file just moves the memory thrashing to a different are in your program (namely when reading/writing it)

Comment: `"w+"` Action if file already exists: destroy contents - see  [`std::fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)

Comment: 1) Added mmbytes value. 2) Yes, there will be some thrashing, but access is by large blocks sequentially, advancing to next block every minute or so. 3) so? fopen with "r+" is that it?

Comment: *access is by large blocks sequentially, advancing to next block every minute or so*  That is just about the most suboptimal way to use `mmap()`.  `mmap()` is **S-L-O-W**, especially for sequential reads where data is read only once.  And if the file is larger than memory, you **WILL** thrash your VM.  Just use `open()` with `O_DIRECT`, `read()` the data, and bypass the page cache since the data is larger than memory and caching it would be useless.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , thanks, Sam  already suggested open instead of fopen, but I dont understand your other suggestion: use open, and read/write manually without mmap?

Comment: @Kostas  Yes - use `open()` with the `O_DIRECT` flag to use direct IO and bypass the page cache.  `int fd=open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_DIRECT, 0666);` (assuming Linux).  Then just use `[p]read()`/`[p]write()` to read or write data to the file.  That will bypass the page cache - which does you no good here because you only read each byte of data once.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The problem is that the access pattern is not exactly in nonoverlapping blocks, it is only overall contiguous, but not strictly, and if I were to figure out which bytes need saving and which reading, I would then move the application to MPI because it has the typical stencil and border region update patterns. Can I just disable auto-flushing to speed things up?

Comment: @Kostas Well, that makes things a pain to use `[p]read()` then, which is one huge advantage of `mmap()` - **simple** code.  If what you're doing is fast enough, don't worry about it then.  There's no point is spending a lot of time writing much more complex code just to go faster if you're already running fast enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w+");
```

I refer you to `fopen`'s manual page, which describes "w+" as follows:

```
       w+     Open  for  reading  and writing.  The file is created if it does
              not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is  positioned
              at the beginning of the file.
```

I specifically draw your attention to the "it is truncated" part. In other words, if there's anything in an existing file this ends up nuking it from high orbit.

Depending on what else you're doing "a" will work better.

Even better would be to forget `fopen` entirely, and simply use `open`:

```
int fd=open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
```

There's your file descriptor, without jumping through any hoops. The file gets created, and left untouched if it already exists.